# Force tabs redraw in chrome

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, xfce, titlebar

I use Ubuntu with XFCE4, after an update few weeks ago something has happened to my google-chrome (version>40), when i unminimize the window the title-bar/tab-bar does not redraw, here an example:

[image: after unminize]

If i pass the mouse over a tab it re-appears

[image: after mouse-over]

The only way to force title-bar redraw is to change tab or uniminize another window.
How can i solve this problem?

EDIT:
this happen even on chromium.

Comment: Anything new on this issue? I am using Chrome 42 and still having this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot confirm the bug but my problem is similar to the one present in this report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1309801

SOLUTION:

run chrome with the option:

```
--disable-gpu-compositing
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a problem with the latest version of google chrome.

They probably know about it. It's a shame that they decided to release the latest version without fixing it.

Comment: you are right, this does not happens for version 39 or older.